# How to compare data in column 0 in different datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Edited :
[Datagridview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsAM2.png)
I want to do this but the problem is I don't know how.

This is how it should be.In every row in data grid view 1 I will search value in data grid view 2, if there are same value i will save new value as good in the other column then if not found i will save new. if in data grid view 2 has data but in the data grid view 1 don't have i will save missing .

Here's my code

```
 For Each dgv1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For dgva As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            For dgvb As Integer = dgva + 1 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
                If (dgv1.Cells(0).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(dgvb).Cells(0).Value) Then
                    MsgBox(dgv1.Cells(0).Value & "," & DataGridView2.Rows(dgvb).Cells(0).Value)
                Else
                    MsgBox(dgv1.Cells(0).Value & "," & DataGridView2.Rows(dgvb).Cells(0).Value)

                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You need to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Generally you want to work with the data not the UI controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to iterate through each row, use a For/Each loop.

Inside your loop you should check for two things using a conditional If/Then statement:

1. Is the currently iterated row not a blank row
2. Is the currently iterated value contained in any row in DataGridView2

If both of these conditions are met then you would do something (though I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, I think that there may be a language barrier).

Here is a quick example:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)
    If Not row.IsNewRow AndAlso DataGridView2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Any(Function(r) r.Cells(0).Value.Equals(row.Cells(0).Value)) Then
        'Do something...
    End If
Next
```

Edit - I forgot to mention that I assume that the value you're wanting to compare is located in the first column. If that is not the case, then you would need to change `.Cells(0)` to the desired column index.

Comment: see my codes, it shows only the row(0) in datagridview1 and row(1) onwards in datagridview2

Comment: sir it works i try when the condition met it will message good and if not not good.